# Why does this homomorphism induce a homomorphism on the quotient groups?

Tags: group-theory

Suppose that $C_1\unlhd B_1\leq A_1$ and $C_2\unlhd B_2\leq A_2$, where $A_i,B_i,C_i$ are groups for $i=1,2$, and suppose that we have a homomorphism $f:A_1\to A_2$. If $f(B_1)\leq B_2$ and $f(C_1)\leq C_2$, then $f$ induces the homomorphisms $f:B_1\to B_2$ and $f:C_1\to C_2$. But then I've also read that $f$ induces a homomorphism $\overline{f}:B_1/C_1\to B_2/C_2$. Why?

Comment: Hint: In this type of problem, you need to write down the natural function and then prove that it is well defined.  For $f:B_1\rightarrow B_2$ and $f:C_1\rightarrow C_2$, you just use the restriction function (just use $f$ but only allow inputs from $B_1$ and $B_2$.  For the quotient situation, let $\overline{f}([b])=[f(b)]$ where brackets represent classes in the quotients (you will need to prove that the map is well-defined).

Comment: This is the general case of how a chain map induces homomorphisms for the homology sequence, correct?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a homomorphism $f:B_1\to B_2$, by composing this with the natural map from $B_2\to B_2/C_2$, you can get a homomorphism
$$g:B_1\to B_2/C_2$$

It now remains to show that this homomorphism is defined on $B_1/C_1$ - i.e. that $C_1\le\ker g $. This follows from the fact that $f(C_1)\le C_2$.